# Two certificate server beeing requested with Postman/Curl/Wget resulting in failure, while browser requests are OK

Tags: google-chrome, curl, postman, ssl-certificate, wget

Our server uses two certificates:

- CERT1: is for two way authentication with our clients which use self signed certificates and a private CA.
- CERT2: is a standard GoDaddy cert, which any browser will trust, but not the clients.

Accessing the server via browser works great, as the second cert is correctly parsed and verified. The address bar states "Connection is secure". However, when using `Postman`/`Curl` or `wget` to access the same server an error is thrown. Postman beeing most explicit stating

```
SSL Error: Unable to verify the first Certificate
```

My questions in this setting:
Where does the difference in behaviour come from? Are browsers just more forgiving with certificates?
Do I have to use some special settings for e.g. Postman to access the page, thus force it to also look for the second cert too?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding GNU `Wget` there are numerous [HTTPS (SSL/TLS) Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html) and catch that

> To support encrypted HTTP (HTTPS) downloads, Wget must be compiled
> with an external SSL library.

So first thing to check is if your wget can https at all, in order to do so run

```
wget --version
```

if you see `+https` somewhere in output then it has https support. In such case you might start to try described options to make it work. If you do not care about security then you might use `--no-check-certificate` but note that its' description suggest that

> For self-signed/internal certificates, you should download the
> certificate and verify against that instead of forcing this insecure
> mode.

I am not sure which options exactly and how you should use but following seems to be potentially relevant

```
--certificate=file
--private-key=file
--ca-certificate=file
--ca-directory=directory
```

depending on what files you do have.

Comment: wget knows https, and any website works just fine. However this is an issue with a two certificate server.